# JLabel NullPointerException

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jlabel

Having problem with JLabel getting NullPointerException, and I have no clue at all what is the problem. Problem is with the "beskjed" JLabel.

The "endeligPris1" JLabel has also a setText in a different method, but it's no problem with that JLabel.

Any help will be thankful.

```
public class Salgsvindu extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener
{
     private JPanel vinduPanel, brukerPanel, infoPanel, jtfPanel, displayPanel, beskjedPanel,      radioPanel;
     private JButton bekreft1, bekreft2, bekreft3;
     private JLabel fornavn, etternavn, nasjonalitet, adresse, fdato, genus, tlf, pris, typerkort, kundenr, endeligPris1, endeligPris2, heiser;
     private JLabel beskjed;
     private JTextField jtfFornavn, jtfEtternavn, jtfAdresse, jtfFdato, jtfTlf, jtfKundenr;
     private JComboBox kortTyperCombo1  = new JComboBox();
     private JComboBox kortTyperCombo2 = new JComboBox();
     private JComboBox nasjonalitetCombo = new JComboBox();
     private JComboBox heisCombo = new JComboBox();
     private JTextArea display;
     private final static String BUTTONPANEL = "Ny Bruker";
     private final static String TEXTPANEL = "Nytt Kort";

public JPanel salgsvinduNyBruker()
{

    bekreft1 = new JButton("Bekreft kjøp");


    fornavn = new JLabel("Fornavn:");
    etternavn = new JLabel("Etternavn:");
    adresse = new JLabel("Adresse:");
    nasjonalitet = new JLabel("Nasjonalitet:");
    fdato = new JLabel("Fødselsdato:");
    genus = new JLabel("Kjønn");
    tlf = new JLabel("Telefonnummer:");
    pris = new JLabel("Pris:");
    endeligPris1 = new JLabel();
    typerkort = new JLabel("Typerkort:");
    beskjed = new JLabel();

    jtfFornavn = new JTextField(7);
    jtfEtternavn = new JTextField(7);
    jtfAdresse = new JTextField(7);
    jtfFdato = new JTextField(7);
    jtfTlf = new JTextField(7);

    JRadioButton jrbMann = new JRadioButton("M", false);
    JRadioButton jrbKvinne = new JRadioButton("K", false);
    radioPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0));
    radioPanel.add(jrbMann);
    radioPanel.add(jrbKvinne);
    ButtonGroup radioGenus = new ButtonGroup();
    radioGenus.add(jrbMann);
    radioGenus.add(jrbKvinne);


    //Bunn JPanel til å legge resten på.
    JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout())
    {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics grphcs)
        {

            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) grphcs;
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            GradientPaint gp = new GradientPaint(0, 0,
                    getBackground().brighter().brighter(), 0, getHeight(),
                    getBackground().darker().darker());

            g2d.setPaint(gp);
            g2d.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

            super.paintComponent(grphcs);
        }
    };

    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Logo.png")));
    btnPanel.add( label , BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    JPanel regPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(9,2));
    regPanel.setOpaque(false);
    btnPanel.add(regPanel, BorderLayout.LINE_START);



    regPanel.add(fornavn);
    regPanel.add(jtfFornavn);
    regPanel.add(etternavn);
    regPanel.add(jtfEtternavn);
    regPanel.add(adresse);
    regPanel.add(jtfAdresse);
    regPanel.add(genus);
    regPanel.add(radioPanel);
    regPanel.add(nasjonalitet);
    regPanel.add(nasjonalitetCombo);
    regPanel.add(fdato);
    jtfFdato.setText("yyyyMMdd");
    regPanel.add(jtfFdato);
    regPanel.add(tlf);
    regPanel.add(jtfTlf);
    regPanel.add(typerkort);
    kortTyperCombo1.addItemListener(this);
    regPanel.add(kortTyperCombo1);
    regPanel.add(pris);
    regPanel.add(endeligPris1);
    bekreft1.addActionListener(this);
    btnPanel.add(bekreft1, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

    btnPanel.add(beskjed, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    btnPanel.setOpaque(true);
    lastKortTyper();
    lastNasjonalitet();
    return btnPanel;
}

public void jtfNyBrukerTilString()
{
    Tidspunkt t = new Tidspunkt();
    BekreftNyBruker b = new BekreftNyBruker();



    String dbFornavn = jtfFornavn.getText();
    String dbEtternavn = jtfEtternavn.getText();
    String dbFdat = jtfFdato.getText();
    int dbFdato = Integer.parseInt(dbFdat);
    String dbTlf = jtfTlf.getText();
    String dbkortTyper = (String)kortTyperCombo1.getSelectedItem();
    String dbNasjonalitet = (String)nasjonalitetCombo.getSelectedItem();
    int dbStartDato = t.getDateTime(); 
    int dbSluttDato = 0;



    b.bekreft(dbFornavn, dbEtternavn, dbFdato, dbTlf, dbkortTyper, dbNasjonalitet, dbStartDato, dbSluttDato);


}


/**The method were I get the NullPointerException. Getting NullPointerException in any case what I setText as.**/

public void registrertNyB(String fornavn, String etternavn, String kortType, int kortNr, int kundeNr)
{
    beskjed.setText("problem"); // NullPointerException here.
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    if(e.getSource() == bekreft1)
        jtfNyBrukerTilString();
}
}
```

The another class.

```
public class BekreftNyBruker
{

public void bekreft(String dbFornavn, String dbEtternavn, int dbFdato, String dbTlf, String dbkortTyper, String dbNasjonalitet, int dbStartDato, int dbSluttDato)
{

    if("Dag".equals(dbkortTyper))
    {
        dbSluttDato = dbStartDato;
    }
    else
    {
        dbSluttDato = 0;
    }  

    finnesBruker( dbFornavn, dbEtternavn, dbFdato, dbTlf, dbkortTyper, dbNasjonalitet, dbStartDato, dbSluttDato);
}




public static void finnesBruker( String fornavn, String etternavn, int fdato, String tlf, String kortTyper, String nasjonalitet, int startDato, int sluttDato)
{
    Connection con = null;
    DatabaseConnection d = new DatabaseConnection();


    try
    {
        Class.forName(d.getDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(d.getUrl() + d.getDb(), d.getUser(), d.getPass());

        try
        {

            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Fornavn, Etternavn, FDato, Telefon, landskode_Land FROM kundetabell WHERE Fornavn = ? AND Etternavn = ? AND FDato = ? AND Telefon = ? AND landskode_Land = ?");
            st.setString(1, fornavn);
            st.setString(2, etternavn);
            st.setInt(3, fdato);
            st.setString(4, tlf);
            st.setString(5, nasjonalitet);
            ResultSet res = st.executeQuery();

            String fnavn = "";
            String enavn = "";
            String ttlf = "";
            String nasj = "";
            int ffdato = 0;

            while(res.next())
            {
                fnavn = res.getString("Fornavn");
                enavn = res.getString("Etternavn");
                ffdato = res.getInt("FDato");
                ttlf = res.getString("Telefon");
                nasj = res.getString("landskode_Land");

            }

            if(fornavn.equals(fnavn) && etternavn.equals(enavn) && fdato == ffdato && tlf.equals(ttlf) && nasjonalitet.equals(nasj) )
            {
                //< Kode som skriver ut i displayet at brukeren finnes fra før >
            } 
            else
            {
                nyBruker( fornavn, etternavn, fdato, tlf, kortTyper, nasjonalitet, startDato, sluttDato);
            }



            st.close();
            res.close();
            con.close();

        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(BekreftNyBruker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, s);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(BekreftNyBruker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}


public static void nyBruker(String fornavn, String etternavn, int fdato, String tlf, String kortTyper, String nasjonalitet, int startDato, int sluttDato)
{
    Connection con = null;

    DatabaseConnection d = new DatabaseConnection();


    try
    {
        Class.forName(d.getDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(d.getUrl() + d.getDb(), d.getUser(), d.getPass());

        try
        {
            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO kundetabell(Fornavn, Etternavn, FDato, Telefon, landskode_land) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            st.setString(1, fornavn);
            st.setString(2, etternavn);
            st.setInt(3, fdato);
            st.setString(4, tlf);
            st.setString(5, nasjonalitet);
            st.executeUpdate();

            st.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(BekreftNyBruker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, s);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(BekreftNyBruker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }

    hentKortInfo(fornavn, etternavn, fdato, tlf, kortTyper, nasjonalitet, startDato, sluttDato);

} 


public static void hentKortInfo(String fornavn, String etternavn, int fdato, String tlf, String kortTyper, String nasjonalitet, int startDato, int sluttDato)
{
    Connection con = null;
    DatabaseConnection d = new DatabaseConnection();


    try
    {
        Class.forName(d.getDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(d.getUrl() + d.getDb(), d.getUser(), d.getPass());

        try
        {
            PreparedStatement state = con.prepareStatement("SELECT Klipp, TypeNr FROM billettypetabell WHERE Billettnavn = ?");
            state.setString(1, kortTyper);
            ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery();

            int antallKlipp = 0; 
            int typeNr = 0;

            while(rs.next())
            {
                antallKlipp = rs.getInt("Klipp");
                typeNr = rs.getInt("TypeNr");
            }
            state.close();
            rs.close();
            con.close();

            hentKundeNr(fornavn, etternavn, fdato, tlf, kortTyper, nasjonalitet, startDato, sluttDato, antallKlipp, typeNr);
        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {
            System.out.println("Feil3");
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

public static void hentKundeNr(String fornavn, String etternavn, int fdato, String tlf, String kortTyper, String nasjonalitet, int startDato, int sluttDato, int antallKlipp, int typeNr)
{
    Connection con = null;
    DatabaseConnection d = new DatabaseConnection();


    try
    {
        Class.forName(d.getDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(d.getUrl() + d.getDb(), d.getUser(), d.getPass());

        try
        {

            PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement("SELECT KundeNr FROM kundetabell WHERE Fornavn = ? AND Etternavn = ? AND FDato = ? AND Telefon = ? AND landskode_Land = ?");
            stat.setString(1, fornavn);
            stat.setString(2, etternavn);
            stat.setInt(3, fdato);
            stat.setString(4, tlf);
            stat.setString(5, nasjonalitet);
            ResultSet res = stat.executeQuery();

            int kundeNr = 0; 

             while(res.next())
            {
                kundeNr = res.getInt("KundeNr");
            }
            stat.close();
            res.close();
            con.close();

            settInnkort(fornavn, etternavn, fdato, tlf, kortTyper, nasjonalitet, startDato, sluttDato, antallKlipp, typeNr, kundeNr);
        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(BekreftNyBruker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, s);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(BekreftNyBruker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}

public static void settInnkort(String fornavn, String etternavn, int fdato, String tlf, String kortTyper, String nasjonalitet, int startDato, int sluttDato, int antallKlipp, int typeNr, int kundeNr)
{
    Connection con = null;
    DatabaseConnection d = new DatabaseConnection();


    try
    {
        Class.forName(d.getDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(d.getUrl() + d.getDb(), d.getUser(), d.getPass());

        try
        {               
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO korttabell(StartDato, SluttDato, AntallKlipp, BillettypeTabell_TypeNr, Kundetabell_KundeNr)" + 
                    "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            stmt.setInt(1, startDato );
            stmt.setInt(2, sluttDato );
            stmt.setInt(3, antallKlipp );
            stmt.setInt(4, typeNr );
            stmt.setInt(5, kundeNr );
            stmt.executeUpdate();


            hentKundeNr(fornavn, etternavn, kortTyper, startDato, sluttDato, antallKlipp, typeNr, kundeNr);

            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(BekreftNyBruker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, s);
        }   
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(BekreftNyBruker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }

}

public static void hentKundeNr(String fornavn, String etternavn, String kortType, int startDato, int sluttDato, int antallKlipp, int typeNr,int kundeNr)
{
    Connection con = null;
    DatabaseConnection d = new DatabaseConnection();


    try
    {
        Class.forName(d.getDriver());
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(d.getUrl() + d.getDb(), d.getUser(), d.getPass());

        try
        {

            PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("SELECT KortNr FROM korttabell WHERE StartDato = ? AND SluttDato = ? AND "
                    + "AntallKlipp = ? AND billettypetabell_TypeNr = ? AND kundetabell_KundeNr = ?");
            st.setInt(1, startDato);
            st.setInt(2, sluttDato);
            st.setInt(3, antallKlipp);
            st.setInt(4, typeNr);
            st.setInt(5, kundeNr);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

            int kortNr = 0; 

             while(rs.next())
            {
                kortNr = rs.getInt("KortNr");
            }
            st.close();
            rs.close();
            con.close();

            Salgsvindu s = new Salgsvindu();
            s.registrertNyB(fornavn, etternavn, kortType, kortNr, kundeNr);

        }
        catch (SQLException s)
        {
            Logger.getLogger(BekreftNyBruker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, s);
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(BekreftNyBruker.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
    }
}
}
```

StackTrace

```
May 11, 2013 10:28:54 PM skisenter.BekreftNyBruker hentKundeNr
SEVERE: null
java.lang.NullPointerException
at skisenter.Salgsvindu.registrertNyB(Salgsvindu.java:312)
at skisenter.BekreftNyBruker.hentKundeNr(BekreftNyBruker.java:334)
at skisenter.BekreftNyBruker.settInnkort(BekreftNyBruker.java:283)
at skisenter.BekreftNyBruker.hentKundeNr(BekreftNyBruker.java:241)
at skisenter.BekreftNyBruker.hentKortInfo(BekreftNyBruker.java:189)
at skisenter.BekreftNyBruker.nyBruker(BekreftNyBruker.java:151)
at skisenter.BekreftNyBruker.finnesBruker(BekreftNyBruker.java:88)
at skisenter.BekreftNyBruker.bekreft(BekreftNyBruker.java:35)
at skisenter.Salgsvindu.jtfNyBrukerTilString(Salgsvindu.java:261)
at skisenter.Salgsvindu.actionPerformed(Salgsvindu.java:523)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:710)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:669)
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:667)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:683)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:681)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:680)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

Comment: Please post all involved method and class declaration.

Comment: The two code snippets don't make any relationship in your question. You must be calling registrertNyB before initializing your label in salgsvinduNyBruker. can you provide more details ?

Comment: Post the stack trace of the exception. It tells exactly where the exception happens and which method calls are involved.

Comment: Has update the code with all related methods.

Comment: *"Has update the code with all related methods."*  Until it is fixed, how can you know what is relevant?  Until you post an SSCCE, how can we match the line numbers to your code?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace, it seems that beskjed must be null at the time of the call.  I can see one place where beskjed gets initialized, but I cannot see where the method that initializes it (salgsvinduNyBruker) gets called.  It is possible that it is called and then beskjed is set to null afterwards, but more likely beskjed is not getting initialized.  Look for all references to beskjed in the code, put it in a debugger, this shouldn't be hard to find.